# Why "jouant" as in "jouant au foot"?

Tags: grammaire

Why use "jouant" in "jouant au foot"? "Jouant" is not a regular conjunction of  jouir yet is used regarding soccer.

Comment: That would be for the verb _jouer_, not _jouir_ (typo?). Do you have more context though? Or more details about what you want to know?

Answer (score 6):

*Jouant* is the present participle of *jouer* (to play) so *jouant au foot* is "playing soccer/football"

You mention *jouir* (to enjoy, to have an orgasm) which would have led to the very unlikely *jouissant au foot*…